# Avenir Next: odd 'u' height

Tags: fonts, typography, typesetting

I've recently inherited a brand which uses Avenir Next as its primary font. Looking through previous documents I have noticed the height of certain characters seem to be off, with the <kbd>u</kbd> being the most noticable.

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?  Which software did you use to render that image?

Comment: And, more importantly, at what zoom size? Drawing text on the screen *always* distorts the font. (Unless your font happens to be drawn as a bitmap to start with. But even then it might.) If this is to be printed: do not worry about it at all. It's your screen.

Comment: Is the u definitely in the same font as the other letters? Not a character with an unusual accent or something that has defaulted? You can test this by re-typing the word and seeing if it looks different.

Comment: Response to all - The font is Avenir, same size etc. This happens when zooming out in some software (InDesign, Acrobat). Retyping the word doesnt change the character. This is a screenshot.

Comment: Not only the u is affected. The strokes for the e and t appear too bold. The stem of the s is irregular. Most likely, the font has become corrupt and should be refreshed. Introduce yourself to the Monotype support team. – Stan 1 min ago    edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some letters look odd at 100% but not 200%?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/why-do-some-letters-look-odd-at-100-but-not-200)

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion on this OP?

Answer (score 3):

Avenir is a professional typeface family used by many, so its very likely that your copy may have been corrupted in some way. If the copy has been legally purchased this will not happen. You should check with whoever paid for this and make sure you have the right files.

Comment: We have a Monotype library subscription, so this copy was legally obtained :)

Comment: Still very unlikely to have this happening on Monotype. Make sure its not a preview issue or something related to your software. The font looks fine on their web preview: https://catalog.monotype.com/family/linotype/avenir-next. Ultimately, contact their support team.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe apps often use custom font rendering algorithms intended to work very fast to cope with complex documents. Unfortunately, they aren't always completely accurate. If this is the issue, a fix is to select View ▸ Display Performance ▸ High Quality Display. Although this will slow your computer down a bit, on modern computers for simple documents it's actually not much of an issue.

Answer (score -3):

Use font-size unit pt instead of px and you'll get a more consistent and crisp result

Comment: Hi user129735, here at GDSE we like longer answers, that don't just explain _how_ but also _why_. Could you [edit] your answer to include more information, and maybe a screenshot comparing points and pixels as verification? Thanks! Feel free to browse the site, leave more answers, upvote quality content and maybe ask a question of your own.