# Font hinting, and/or something else? Avenir Next letter U (mainly) appears larger and elevated

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, visual-artifacts

Avenir Next (mainly the bold weight, but also Roman) displays incorrectly at sizes around 20pt and at a viewing size of between 75% and 100% in the Adobe Creative Suite apps. The result is filling in and distortion of the letters but most noticeably the enlargement of some, such as the letter u, then y and v etc. And my files when exported to jpeg and PDF for online viewing perpetuate this distortion and enlargement.

I know this topic has previously been discussed here and 'artifacts' was mentioned. But to me, it doesn't make sense that the issue goes away when the font is used in a different application. Or the file that contains that font is opened up in a different application.

For instance. I can open up an Acrobat PDF file that demonstrates this issue into Preview and it completely disappears.

In trying to find an explanation or fix for this (other than use a different font):

• Adobe support told me this is 'normal behaviour' and they dont support third-party fonts anyway.

• Apple can't offer a solution as it works fine in their software.

• Linotype/Monotype won't engage at all, pointing me back to Apple as the vendor.

In case the Apple version has been tinkered with to work best with only their apps (would they do that I wonder?), I notice there's a newer, much more expensive Pro version of Avenir Next now on MyFonts and I'm wondering if this might fix things. Or if I'm wasting my time (and money).

It would be such a shame if I had to stop using this font.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi pac, it would help immensely if you could [edit] your question and add some example images of what you're expecting to see and what you're actually seeing.

Comment: Hi pac. Welcome to GDSE.  Without being able to see anything, questions like these are very difficult to answer. For example, I don't even have access to that font to try it out, and I'm certainly not buying it just to find out. Can you please add an image of what the font is supposed to look like, and a screenshot of the problem. Thanks.  Also is this just affecting the font rendering in InDesign, or can you see it on the files you output (in the PDF for example)?

Comment: If you use the font for print it doesn't really matter how it renders on screen (although it is very annoying), so I assume you need to make PDFs for screen. I am familiar with the problem with "bad hinting" or whatever causes the problem, but I can't reproduce it right now - can't find a "bad font". But I've sometimes been able to make a nicer looking PDF if I export an *interactive* PDF instead of a *print* PDF. Have you tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avenir Next: odd 'u' height](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110974/avenir-next-odd-u-height)

Comment: There is something wonky with Avenir Next and it properly rendering on the screen. At certain sizes, things do no adjust, so some letters will appear bolder when they are not. I am having issues with l's looking like they are a different weight and certain zoom scale sizes. Unclear how to resolve. But thought I would add this here.

Answer (score 0):

Your case invites easily one to search downloadables from grey font sites, who have thousands free fonts and in addition they have at least as many high cost commercial fonts freely downloadable. They have a disclaimer, for ex. this font is not ours, you must pay to the copyright owner what he wants, if you are going to use this.

NOTE: Using commercial fonts without paying is illegal, in some countries even having them is illegal. And you can get anything harmful that malware developers have ever invented. Check, if you can get legal trial versions from established commercial font distributors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Adobe apps may use custom font rendering algorithms intended to work very fast, so they can quickly load complex documents with many fonts and pictures. Unfortunately, they aren't always completely accurate. If this is the issue, a fix is often to select View ▸ Display Performance ▸ High Quality Display. Although this will slow your computer down a bit, on modern computers for simple documents it's actually not much of an issue.

What I don't know is why you'd see this in a pdf generated with InDesign–while the rendering in InDesign can be a little off, it should have the font outlines perfect inside its memory. You are exporting conventionally as a pdf, not doing something weird like taking a screenshot? An image of the problem and workflow would help us understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem with a number of truetype fonts. The pdf will render fonts of all shapes and sizes along with sketchy tracking and kearning.

The only way I can get things to work is to outline the fonts in Indesign before exporting to pdf. Of course that means keeping a non-outlined version for editing but I don't have any other fix.